# Cls is undefined on my testing module nestjs

Tags: node.js, testing, nestjs, e2e-testing

I have an interceptor that **works in production** but doesn't work when I run tests. The implementation of the test module is the following:

```js
 const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule]
  }).compile()
  const app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication<NestFastifyApplication>(
    new FastifyAdapter()
  )

  // Global response interceptor
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ResponseInterceptor())
  // DTO Validation Global configuration
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      forbidUnknownValues: true,
      whitelist: true,
      transform: true,
      stopAtFirstError: true,
      transformOptions: {
        ignoreDecorators: true
      }
    })
  )
  await app.init()
  await app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance().ready()
  const http = new HttpClient(app)

///...
```

@interceptor
The interceptor is :

```js
@Injectable()
export class InjectRequestContextInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly cls: ClsService) {}
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest()
    if (['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH'].includes(request.method)) {
      this.cls.set(REQUEST_CONTEXT, {
        method: request.method,
        id: request.params?.id ?? request.params?._id ?? undefined,
        params: request.params,
        query: request.query,
        body: request.body
      })
    }
    return next.handle()
  }
}

export function InjectRequestContext(): any {
  return applyDecorators(UseInterceptors(InjectRequestContextInterceptor))
}
```

@decorator
The error is on the decorator that use this interceptor there, **cls** and related context are undefined:

```js
@ValidatorConstraint({ async: true })
@Injectable()
export class ExcludeIfConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  constructor(
    @Inject(MONGODB_CONNECTION_MAIN) private readonly dbMain: Db,
    private readonly cls: ClsService
  ) {}

  async validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments): Promise<boolean> {
    const [condition, requiredParams, collection] = args.constraints
    const obj = args.object

    const reqContext = this.cls?.get(REQUEST_CONTEXT)

    if (reqContext == null)
      throw new BadRequestException(
        'Missing @InjectRequestContext() in controller or @ExcludeIfModule() in module'
      )
//...
```

I don't know where is the error, I supposed that it was on the interceptor and not on this decorator, but I don't know,

I have tested too with:

```js
//..
providers: [
      {
        provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
        useClass: InjectRequestContextInterceptor
      }
    ]
//...
```

and

```js
  const cls = app.get(ClsService)
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new InjectRequestContextInterceptor(cls))
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ResponseInterceptor())
```

and other variations but nothing.

Comment: Does your interceptor have `@Injectable()` on it?

Comment: yes, I'll edit the script, sorry if I have omitted that